# Another one concerning array adapters (android)

Tags: android, loops, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have an `ArrayAdapter` being populated with `ints` from a `while` loop, we will say from 3 to 18. These numbers are put into a `Spinner`.

My question is: is it possible to have a given number, say 8, be automatically selected?

EDIT: Changed checked to selected

Comment: What do you mean by automatically checked? Please post some example code and clarify your description.

Comment: I mean to have the number 8 be checked when the activity starts. Unfortunately im no where near my computer to show the code.

Comment: By checked, do you mean that an item is selected in a spinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to find out the position of this number in your `ArrayAdapter` (e.g. 8):

`int pos = myAdapter.getPosition(8);`

Then just set selection:

`mySpinner.setSelection(pos);`